# Redirect to a content from a DIV using CSS

Tags: html, css, redirect

How I can redirect by pusching a button to a content from a DIV just with CSS? I mean..when i want to push a button with something i want to show in that content to appear a text and when I push another button, to clear that content and appear another text.

Comment: Please provide a starting point by adding code to your question, or via CodePen or JSFiddle. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: keyword maybe : toggle ?